# How to fire React Hooks after event

Tags: reactjs

I am quite new to React and how to use hooks. I am aware that the following code doesn't work, but I wrote it to display what I would like to achieve. Basically I want to use useQuery after something changed in an input box, which is not allowed (to use a hook in a hook or event).

So how do I correctly implement this use case with react hooks? I want to load data from GraphQL when the user gives an input.

```
import React, { useState, useQuery } from "react";
import { myGraphQLQuery } from "../../api/query/myGraphQLQuery";

// functional component
const HooksForm = props => {
  // create state property 'name' and initialize it
  const [name, setName] = useState("Peanut");
  const handleNameChange = e => {
    const [loading, error, data] = useQuery(myGraphQLQuery)
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input
            type="text"
            name="name"
            value={name}
            onChange={handleNameChange}
          />
        </label>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default HooksForm;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `useLazyQuery` (https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-hooks/#uselazyquery) if you wan't to control when the request gets fired, like so:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useLazyQuery } from "@apollo/client";
import { myGraphQLQuery } from "../../api/query/myGraphQLQuery";

// functional component
const HooksForm = props => {
  // create state property 'name' and initialize it
  const [name, setName] = useState("Peanut");
  const [doRequest, { called, loading, data }] = useLazyQuery(myGraphQLQuery)

  const handleNameChange = e => {
    setName(e.target.value);
    doRequest();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input
            type="text"
            name="name"
            value={name}
            onChange={handleNameChange}
          />
        </label>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default HooksForm;
```

Comment: Updated document link https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#executing-queries-manually

Answer (score -1):

So whenever the name changes, you want to fire the query? I think you want `useEffect`.

```
const handleNameChange = e => setName(e.target.value);

useEffect(() => {
  // I'm assuming you'll also want to pass name as a variable here somehow
  const [loading, error, data] = useQuery(myGraphQLQuery);
}, [name]);
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I get the following error message: React Hook "useQuery" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

Answer (score -2):

I think you could call the function inside the `useEffect` hook, whenever the name changes. You could debounce it so it doesn't get executed at every letter typing, but something like this should work:

```
handleNameChange = (e) => setName(e.target.value);

useEffect(() => {
  const ... = useQuery(...);
}, [name])
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I get the following error message: React Hook "useQuery" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

Comment: @nino can you try to wrap this hook in a function and call the function instead?

Comment: You can't call hooks inside functions! :) Hooks have to be on top-level of your component.