# Using React hooks to fire events with side effects, like onClick() calling fetch()

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I use React with hooks, using `useState()` for the internal state and `useEffect()` for external side effects like calling a web service, as it is described in React's documentation.

In this example I have a button, and a click on the button should call a web service. This works with `useEffect()` the first time on initialization but further button clicks will not call the web service.

Now my hacky solution is to introduce an additional state called `hackIndex` which is incremented each time the button is clicked, but that does not seem particular elegant:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
  const [answers, setAnswers] = useState([]);
  // very ugly hack
  const [hackIndex, setHackIndex] = useState(0);
  // when hackIndex changes, gets data from web service and adds it to answers array
  // also called when the page is initialized, but we can ignore that for this question
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => setAnswers([...answers, json.title]));
  }, [hackIndex]);
  // returning React JSX
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <button
          onClick={e => {
            setHackIndex(hackIndex + 1);
          }}
        >
          Call web service
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>Collected answers:</div>
      {answers.map(answer => (
        <div>{answer}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I haven't used reducers yet, as coming from Java and Angular they strike me a bit odd. But `useReducer()` should only use pure functions, so they don't seem to fit.

This is somewhat basic functionality, but I don't find any articles about this problem or anyone asking it. Or I'm missing something completely.

There is a similar question, but it involves Apollo for GraphQL queries using `useQuery()`, whereas I'm using a simple VanillaJS `fetch()` call:
[How to fire React Hooks after event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59308941/how-to-fire-react-hooks-after-events)

Comment: What is the purpose of using `useEffect` and not calling the fetch method directly, or using `useCallback` ?

Comment: Most likely none. It's the way I learned how to do web API calls (using `useEffect()`), but it looks as I do not need it. As Ross Allen's answer showed, I'm doing it wrong all the way.

Comment: remember use `key` in `answers.map` [lists and keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setX` functions returned from `useState` have a [functional update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) ability that takes a function as an argument and calls that function with the previous state value. That enables your `fetchAnswers` to not need access to the previous value of `answers`.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
  const [answers, setAnswers] = useState([]);

  function fetchAnswers() {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => setAnswers(prevAnswers => [...prevAnswers, json.title]));
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchAnswers();
  }, []);

  // returning React JSX
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <button
          onClick={fetchAnswers}
        >
          Call web service
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>Collected answers:</div>
      {answers.map(answer => (
        <div>{answer}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly was I was looking for. I didn't make the mental connection between functional updates and web API calls.